# Alternatives are there to jQuery that work in the same or similar way

Tags: jquery, javascript

I'm looking for alternative JavaScript Libraries to learn as an alternative to jQuery, as I think it would be good to know more than one and so i can broaden what libraries I know.

I'd tried Mootools so far but am not sure what else is just as good.

Any ideas?

Comment: what aspect of jQuery are you most interested in?

Comment: DOM traversing, event handling, ajax and animation mainly

Comment: Do you know how to do the things the libraries do without using a library? That's important to learn.

Comment: Yes. I'd like to know other ways of doing it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

**[Comparison of JavaScript frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks)**

Another good resource:

**[Compare JavaScript frameworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-jsframeworks/index.html)**

Some of the things compared include:

- Selectors
- DOM traversal
- DOM manipulation
- Utility functions
- Event handling
- Ajax

Answer (score 4):

- [Glow](http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/)
- [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/)
- [Protype](http://www.prototypejs.org/)
- [ExtJS](http://extjs.com/)
- [Sproutcore](http://www.sproutcore.com/)
- [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/)

Answer (score 1):

The "Functional" and "Underscore" libraries are interesting, and quite different in purpose than jQuery. Those two libraries don't have much to do with DOM manipullation at all — they're about functional programming, really.

- Functional: http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/
- Underscore: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/

Underscore is designed to play nice with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Not to forget Mootools:
http://mootools.net/